# A good book on measure theory for self study

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request

I have been looking for a book on measure theory and im a bit stuck. I have checked out real analysis by stein and measure theory by tao. These books seem to emphasize a rigorous but intuitive approach. I have also checked out rudin, folland, etc. Which are more standard for a beginning grad course. My question is which book should i go with for self study and is it one of the ones ive checked out or a lesser known book?

Comment: I've heard good things about Cohn's Measure Theory, though I haven't read it myself yet.

Comment: Personally, I’ve used Royden’s *Real Analysis* (third edition) and Wheeden and Zygmund’s *Measure and Integral*. I liked both of these books but prefer Royden’s.

Comment: Back in the day, people liked Bartle’s book. Roy den is the standard if you take a class. Halmos’ book has good things about it. Sacks had a good book. I would get a bunch of sources and read them simultaneously as you don’t have a teacher. Gaps in one source fill another. Also you find the one book that speaks to you more directly than the others and that will be your guide.

Comment: You could try *Measures, integrals and martingales* by R. Schilling. The book is a nice read and has plenty of exercises (solutions are available on the webpage).